Preserve dimensions after using apply function
I have an n by m matrix X, and an array A of dimension (S,m,p). I used want to get an array B of dimension (S,n,p) where B[i,,] equals to X %*% A[i,,].
If I directly use the apply function:apply(A,1,function(x) X %*% x), this gives me a np x S matrix. I'll have to re-arrange it to get to what I want in the following way: array(t(apply(A,1,function(x) X %*% x)), dim=c(S,n,p)).
I read this post. So I further tried using vapply in the following way, and it's indeed slightly faster than apply: B=aperm(vapply(c(1:S), function(i) X %*% A[i,,], matrix(0,n,p)), c(3,1,2)). Note that I also had to use aperm to re-arrange the dimensions for it to be correct.
The same post also talked about assigning the value to something like m[] instead of just m. So I tried the following: B[]=vapply(c(1:S), function(i) X %*% A[i,,], matrix(0,n,p)). This directly returns me an object B which has the correct dimension of (S,n,p). But the values are wrong. I'm curious when I use B[]= instead of B=, what has changed? Why it has got the dimension I wanted, but unexpected results?
This post also mentioned that this syntax: m[] can be used to preserve dimension. But exactly how is it working behind the hood?
I googled a bit but couldn't find anything directly related to this syntax, so I wanted to ask here.

When you use apply it will always return a matrix in column major order, even if the implicit index is by row.

@IRTFM Thanks for the comments! As mentioned above, I'm mainly interested in understanding how this syntax works: m[].

I assume that it just assigns the dimensions of the existing ‘m’ structure to the new ‘m’ structure. Do you have any reason to doubt that assumption?

@IRTFM: ar I see! I was confused because I run these codes one after the other. So when I used B[], its structure was already defined by the codes I've just run where I set its dimension to the way I wanted. Now I understand why when I used B[], it was able to return an object with the dimension I want, but in the wrong order. Thanks!!
